# Process forked from WCF Service is becoming idle

Tags: c#, wcf, process

I'm facing a Weird problem. In my WCF Service, I'm calling a Batch file that will invoke an Application.

```
                ProcessStartInfo appInfo= new ProcessStartInfo("runApp.bat");

                appInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                appInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                appInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

                app.StartInfo = appInfo;
                app.Start();
                app.WaitForExit();
```

Batch file: 
                app.exe "path_of_the_file_needs_to_be_processes_as_argument"

The application called from the Batchfile is becoming idle after say 15-20 seconds(varies). When I check in the Process Explorer, the forked process is available but CPU time is not moving after 15-20 seconds. I have even left this for a Day and still there is not timeout or process completion.

When I execute the batch file seperately the application runs and completes properly.

I'm able to think only two possibilities

1) WCF Service is abandoning the process after sometime due to some kind of time out(but no exception or any other indication)
2) The application I'm calling from the Batch file is executed with limited rights. Because  when I see the application log, I notice the application freezes at a point where it is supposed to write a file to the host PC.

Note: I even tried calling app.exe directly as a Process instead of using a Batch file. The result is exactly same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1, You specify `RedirectStandardOutput`, but you don't actually read its output, so it may be waiting for that to happen.

2, Try to run it with a visible window first to see what happens.

3, Try to run `cmd.exe /c full_path_to\runapp.bat`.

Comment: Thanks a Lot!. That's a Dumb one. Made RedirectStandardOutput=false. It worked :).